# Two of the same commands give different result (output as utf8)

Tags: sql, batch-file

I have a .bat file that contains two commands:

> SQLCMD -S . -d "databaseName" -E -i "path_to_query1.sql" -y0 -s "|" -f o:65001 > outputPath1.json

> SQLCMD -S . -d "databaseName" -E -i "path_to_query2.sql" -y0 -s "|" -f o:65001 > outputPath2.json

The argument -f o:65001 is to output it to utf8 format, but only the second line outputs the query in an utf8 format.

Why is this? Why does it seem that the argument "-f o:65001" only works for the second command?

I checked it by switching the order and then again only the second command outputs the query in utf8 format.

Thanks for any tips on this.

**EDIT**

The solution for my specific problem was to put "chcp 65001" before the SQLCMD's. You then also don't need the argument -f 0:65001

Comment: What about this: path_to_query1.sql vs path_to_query2.sql ?

Comment: you mean one command with "vs" between the query paths?

Comment: No, what is in the file path_to_query1.sql and what is in file  path_to_query2.sql ?

Comment: two sql scripts that output a result query in json format. But when I change the order of the commands, I again get the case that only the second command (so the other query) outputs in utf8 format.

Comment: @VBoka, paths are irrelevant here as OP stated that the results are the same even reversing the query sequence

Comment: Hi @Gerhard, I am not sure it only says when I change the order ?"I checked it by switching the order and then again only the second command outputs the query in utf8 format." Order of what ? What have you checked - OP why not also share with us this other set up you have tried ?

Comment: I highly doubt that this would be of any relevance to `cmd` itself. but before each command can you put `chcp` and compare the codepage results after you've ran the commands?

Comment: @VBoka, no, OP states when he swopped the commands, again the second command is in UTF-8 and not the first.

Comment: @VBoka It's indeed like Gerhard says. The paths seem irrelevant, as when I swap the commands, again only the second command outputs an utf-8 and not the first. I also noticed that when I run the two commands in a separate .bat file, both files don't output an utf-8...

Comment: So basically they work only  if you run them one after another ? I do not know if this is stupid but is there a need or way to commit ?

Comment: See the edit for what looks like the solution to my specific problem..